# I can not access server cloudera manager localhost:7180

Tags: cloudera

Someone working on cloudera in pseudo distributed mode, my problem is that I can not access the server cloudera manager localhost: 7180 after rebooting the machine, despite that I already focused on this server before the machine is extinguished

Answer (score 0):

ssh to cloudera manager node, check which ip it is listening 7180, if it is localhost you have to use port forwarding to open UI. Or if it running on some ip then it should be available directly only if you are on same network and don't have any firewall in between.